# How do I specify which interface (Wifi or Data) over which a UDP packet will be sent in Android?

Tags: android

I want the ability to specify and constrain the interface over which UDP datagrams will be sent.

I want to do this without physically disabling the "non wanted" interface. Assume standard INET connectivity is available over the chosen interface (in fact assume that if both interfaces are active then INET connectivity is available over boti)

Most mobile devices will send data over Wifi (in preference to Data interface) if the Wifi interface is enabled; but I want to know how to grammatically "force" UDP over my chosen interface.

There are similar questions already posted, but no question hits the topic precisely. Also I would like the programmed solution to be available (generically or via support library) as FAR BACK as possible in terms of Android SDK versions.

Please note that question "Android how to select wifi network interface to send udp packet" is old and was NEVER answered.

Answer (score 3):

There is an issue with [cyanide's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44071715) - how does one ascertain the valid WiFi interface value associated with `getName()` for ALL devices, current and future?

The solution I have come up with would entail finding the IP address associated with the WiFi interface, then obtaining a UDP socket which is BOUND to this address. Getting a handle onto the WiFi interface can be done by accessing the `WiFiManager`:

```
 WifiManager wifiManager =
                (WifiManager) context.getApplicationContext ()
                        .getSystemService (Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

.....

 int localInetAddressInt = wifiManager.getDhcpInfo ().ipAddress;

 ByteBuffer tmp = ByteBuffer.allocate (4);

 tmp.putInt (localInetAddressInt);

 InetAddress localInetAddress = InetAddress.getByAddress (tmp.array ());

 DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket (portNumber, localInetAddress);
```

Then, when sending over the `DatagramSocket` (socket), the device SHOULD route the datagram over the appropriate interface, i.e. the interface associated with bound IP address, i.e. the WiFi interface to which the IP address is bound. The IP address would normally be associated with the WiFi interface by the WiFi Access Point via DHCP.

Comment: There is a minor problem there  since getDhcpInfo().ipAddress gives 32 bits, therefore incompatible with IPv6. However, since all LANs are currently follow IP4 protocol,  this probably can be ignored.

Comment: +1 Works. Tried on API Level 25. Minor correction though. The address gets allocated in reverse, so need this `byte swap;
                                                for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {

                                                    swap = tmp.get(i);
                                                    tmp.put(i, tmp.get(3 - i));
                                                    tmp.put(3 - i, swap);
                                                    Log.d("WIFI_Y", String.valueOf(tmp.get(i)));

                                                }` after `tmp.putInt`

Answer (score 2):

Use *NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces*" to get list of all *active* interfaces.

Then for each interface use *NetworkInterface.getName*.For a wifi it will be wlanXX (Samsung and other), tiwlanXX (Motorola), ethXX (HTC) and e0 (Blackberry). With mobile net it most certainly be rmnetXX.

Then you can use NetworkInterface.getInetAddrress for creating socket.

When WiFi is unavailable, only rmnet appears. Similarly, when WiFi is available, rmnet will not appear, even if Mobile Data is enabled.

*Added 30May17* In fact, I doubt that is possible to do what you intend, as it looks like the mobile network is automatically switched off when WiFi is available.

Answer (score 0):

```
WifiManager wifiManager =
            (WifiManager) context.getApplicationContext ()
                    .getSystemService (Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
```

.....

```
 int localInetAddressInt = wifiManager.getDhcpInfo ().ipAddress;

 ByteBuffer tmp = ByteBuffer.allocate (4);

 tmp.putInt (localInetAddressInt);

byte swap; for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) { swap = tmp.get(i); tmp.put(i, tmp.get(3 - i)); tmp.put(3 - i, swap);  }

 InetAddress localInetAddress = InetAddress.getByAddress (tmp.array ());

 DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket (portNumber, localInetAddress);
```

This worked for me!

EDIT:

Nope it doesn't. When Mobile data is ON, it doesn't go via WIFI

Comment: Well if you know that this doesn't work why did you not delete your answer?